# `rustup component add rls --toolchain nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` failed

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

I need to use a Rust nightly feature with the VS-code Rust-language-server.

```
#![feature(generic_associated_types)]
```

So, I did

```
$ rustup default nightly
```

and, vscode rust extension automatically starts

```
$ rustup component add rls --toolchain nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

however,

```
error: component 'rls' for target 'x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu' is unavailable for download for channel 'nightly'
Sometimes not all components are available in any given nightly.
```

I understand what it means, and is there nothing to do?

I mean looks like it's impossible to code with Rust nightly feature in VS-code currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use rust-analyzer instead. Rls is not in active now.

Comment: Thanks! it works. However I have a question. "component 'rls' for target 'x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu' is unavailable for download for channel 'nightly'" seems `rustup` level, and how can the alternative extension resolves the problem since it says " It is a part of a larger rls-2.0 effort to create excellent IDE support for Rust." which means the extension embraces own rls-2.0 inside?
`

Comment: @sailsky Rust-analyzer is rls-2.0. https://rust-lang.github.io/compiler-team/working-groups/rls-2.0/